# Kibana painless script to count the json list size

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, elasticsearch-painless

I have the json data in the elasticsearch index as below:

```
{
  "_index": "tower",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "sadssasadsadsa",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "task": "",
    "event_data": {
      "playbook_uuid": "sasdsad21w",
      "processed": {
        "11.22.33.46": 1,
        "11.22.33.44": 1,
        "11.22.33.45": 1
      },
      "failures": {
        "11.22.33.46": 1
      },
      "changed": {
        "11.22.33.44": 1
      },
      "playbook": "test.yml",
      "ignored": {},
      "ok": {
        "11.22.33.46": 1,
        "11.22.33.44": 4,
        "11.22.33.45": 1
      },
      "dark": {
        "11.22.33.45": 1
      }
    },
    "level": "INFO",
    "event_display": "Playbook Complete",
    "stdout": "\r\nPLAY RECAP *********************************************************************\r\n\u001b[0;33m11.22.33.44\u001b[0m               : \u001b[0;32mok=4   \u001b[0m \u001b[0;33mchanged=1   \u001b[0m unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   \r\n\u001b[0;31m11.22.33.45\u001b[0m               : \u001b[0;32mok=1   \u001b[0m changed=0    \u001b[1;31munreachable=1   \u001b[0m failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   \r\n\u001b[0;31m11.22.33.46\u001b[0m              : \u001b[0;32mok=1   \u001b[0m changed=0    unreachable=0    \u001b[0;31mfailed=1   \u001b[0m skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   \r\n",
    "@version": "1",
    "tags": [
      "tower"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2020-12-24T06:14:20.202Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now i want to create a painless script which will count the size of

```
"processed": {
        "11.22.33.46": 1,
        "11.22.33.44": 1,
        "11.22.33.45": 1
},
"failures": {
        "11.22.33.46": 1
},
"dark": {
        "11.22.33.45": 1
}
```

For example, here the count will look something like

```
processed: 3
failures: 1
dark: 1
```

All these values will be stores in a new field.

I tried using  `return params['_source']['event_data']['processed'].size();` just to get the processed size but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Does not work" doesn't say much ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `script_fields` like so:

```
GET tower/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "ev_data_counts": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def counts_by_status = [:];
          counts_by_status['processed'] = params['_source']['event_data']['processed'].size();
          counts_by_status['failures'] = params['_source']['event_data']['failures'].size();
          counts_by_status['dark'] = params['_source']['event_data']['dark'].size();
          return counts_by_status
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
"hits" : [
  {
    ...
    "fields" : {
      "ev_data_counts" : [
        {
          "processed" : 3,
          "failures" : 1,
          "dark" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: did this help @SUBHAS?